# ARRAYFORMULA to SUMIF on datestamps

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've got data like:

```
06/16/2021 14:35:06    |    10
06/16/2021 15:42:57    |    2
06/16/2021 18:00:48    |    3
06/16/2021 19:11:28    |    7
06/16/2021 20:33:57    |    15
06/17/2021 8:10:40     |    15
06/17/2021 9:17:06     |    14
06/17/2021 10:25:47    |    14
06/17/2021 11:35:05    |    14
```

And want to display a chart that has totals for each day. To collect the days I've got
`=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(INT(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>"")))))`

and I've been able to build up a couple SUMIFs with a single hard-coded value:
`=SUMIF(ARRAYFORMULA(EQ(TO_DATE(INT(A1:A)),$K$2)),TRUE(),B1:B)`
`=SUMIF(ARRAYFORMULA(EQ(TO_DATE(INT(A1:A)),$K$3)),TRUE(),B1:B)`

*(where `K2:K` will be the unique dates from the formula above)*

I'm just missing the final component - removing the hardcoded `K` column values and auto-populating it (with an `ARRAYFORMULA` or `QUERY`). Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should be possible with a single query. See if something like this helps?

```
=ArrayFormula(query({int(A:A), B:B}, "Select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 > 0 group by Col1 label sum(Col2)'' format Col1 'mm/dd/yyyy'", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: It works! What is the essence of the `{int(A:A), B:B}`? I've never seen the curly braces before in a formula

Comment: The curly brackets create a literal array. ={"A", "B"}  creates a 'horizontal' array (here: a single row, two columns wide). The array in the formula simply creates a array of n rows, with two columns: int(A:A) and B:B. Hope that makes sense?